# Multiple plots with matplotlib in a nested while loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, nested-loops

I'm making a program to control a LCR meter (the specifics aren't important). Therefore I need two nested `while` loops (easy example):

```
while x <= stopFrequency:
    y = startVoltage
    while y <= stopVoltage:
        getCapacity = y * 2
        y += stepValueVoltage 
    x += stepValueFrequency
```

Now I need to make a plot for the different frequency's (outer loop) of `y` and `getCapacity`. I can get a plot of `y` and `getCapacity` for one frequency. But for more, I don't know how to get the graphs on one plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put multiple plots ("graphs") on the same axis ("plot"), simply call `plt.plot` once for each plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
markers = itertools.cycle([ '+', '*', ',', 'o', '.', '1', 'p', ])
while x <= stopFrequency:
    y = startVoltage
    ys = []
    vals = []
    while y <= stopVoltage:
        ys.append(y)
        vals.append(getCapacity)
        getCapacity = y * 2
        y += stepValueVoltage
    plt.plot(ys, vals, 
             label = 'x: {0}'.format(x),
             marker = next(markers))
    x += stepValueFrequency
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I needed. I had almost the same code as you, but I placed ys=[] and vals=[] before the first while and that was a wrong move :-) Tx also for the label format, that I didn't knew!

Comment: Maybe I have another small question. Here you use .format. Now every plot has another color, is there also a command to let them have another line genre (like dashed or circles or whatever)?

Comment: I've added some code to show how to assign a different marker to each plot. You can change the particular markers used by redefining the `markers` variable. The available choices are [documented here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) and [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/line_styles.html#pylab-examples-line-styles) shows how to use LaTeX characters as markers too. Since I don't know how many markers you need, I used `itertools.cycle` to make the markers cycle ad infinitum.